# Filtering in Angular using a slight complex boolean condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am struggling slightly with my filters in AngularJS. Essentially, I have a checkbox like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right">
    <label for="include-deleted-search" class="control-label">Include Deleted</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input ng-model="search.includeDeleted" type="checkbox" id="include-deleted-search"/>
</div>
```

which I am trying to use to filter airlines if (the item in the filter is deleted, and includeDeleted is true) or the item in the filter is not deleted.

My table looks like this, but note the { isDeleted: search.includeDeleted } filter is not working as I'd like.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ariline ID</th>
            <th>Airline Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>24hr Telephone</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Deleted</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr dir-paginate="airline in airlines | filter: { airlineName: search.airlineName||'' } | filter: { country: search.countryName||'' } | filter: { isDeleted: search.includeDeleted||!isDeleted }  | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
        <td>{{ airline.airlineId }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.airlineName }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.country }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.telephoneNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ ariline.telephone24Hour }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.emailAddress }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.isDeleted }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I express this as a filter condition? Do I need to write a custom filter? Everything else is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly, you can set the expression based on the `search.includeDelted`. If it's true, return undefined (assuming `isDeleted` is a boolean value) which will not filter any of the items, otherwise return false, which will return only those who are falsy:

```
filter:{isDeleted: search.includeDeleted?undefined:false}
```

Comment: My intention is that if isDeleted is true, and the search.includeDeleted is false, then the item shouldn't make it to the result. I get an Angular error when I include your filter.

Comment: Sorry the error was produces elsewhere in the application. Fixed now. Your logic still doesn't work though unfortunately. I am using Angular version 1.3.15 which is the latest.

Comment: all of your `isDeleted` values are either true or false?

Comment: Yes, they're either true or false. I don't need to handle undefined at the moment. If search.includeDeleted is true or isDeleted is false is essentially the logic.

Comment: it seems to work for me, check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/mjKQ3E2hnwaELFkTXDu7?p=preview

Comment: I see your point. Thank you for taking the time to write that. I have copied your code but it still doesn't work in my application for some reason. I will investigate and get back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77630/discussion-between-serlingpa-and-user3906922).